# How do I pass my page ID to a hidden Wicket form?

Tags: wicket

This is such a simple question, I feel slightly embarrassed asking it. I'm modifying a Wicket website and trying to pass my internal page ID to a hidden form, so it can extracted by JavaScript. But I am a total Wicket noob. Here's my code so far:

```
    Form hiddenForm = new Form("hiddenForm");
    HiddenField test = new HiddenField("pageId");
    hiddenForm.add(test);
    add(hiddenForm);
```

I can get a form to *show up* (well, appear in the source code as it's hidden), but how do 1) set the actual value of the hiddenField, and how do I ensure the field always uses the same ID so JavaScript can easily extract the right value?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
...
hiddenForm.add(new HiddenField<String>("pageId", Model.of("somepageid")));
```

now your HTML source looks like:

```
...
<input wicket:id="pageId" type="hidden" value="somepageid"/>
```

Wicket makes use of Models a lot. [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models) is some reading food for the basics of Wicket models.